# Creation of asset of assets in hypperledger composer

Tags: api, assets, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

i would like to create an asset called item that consists of other items. 
Here is fragment of my model file:

```
namespace org.dps.track

asset Item identified by itemId{
    o String itemId
    o String name
    o String serialNumber
    o String comment
    o Item [] items optional

abstract participant BU identified by buId{
    o String buId
    o String name
    o String country
    o String city
}


participant Manufacturer extends BU{

}

participant Assembler extends BU{

}
```

in rest-server-api i'm trying to post an item that consists of other items, like this:

```
    {
  "$class": "org.dps.track.Item",
  "itemId": "I5",
  "name": "complex",
  "serialNumber": "222",
  "comment": "complex item - consists of many items",
  "items": [
    "org.dps.track.Item#I2", "org.dps.track.Item#I3"
  ],
  "owner": "org.dps.track.Assembler#BU3"
}
```

(of course Item#I2 and Item#I3 are already posted and belong to BU3), when i'm trying to post this, im getting following error

```
    {
  "error": {
    "statusCode": 500,
    "name": "Error",
    "message": "Invalid or missing identifier for Type Item in namespace       org.dps.track",
    "stack": "Error: Invalid or missing identifier for Type Item in namespace org.dps.track\n    at Factory.newResource (/home/composer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-common/lib/factory.js:86:19)\n    at JSONPopulator.convertItem (/home/composer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-common/lib/serializer/jsonpopulator.js:142:50)\n    at JSONPopulator.visitField (/home/composer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-common/lib/serializer/jsonpopulator.js:104:34)\n    at JSONPopulator.visit (/home/composer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-common/lib/serializer/jsonpopulator.js:60:25)\n    at Field.accept (/home/composer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-common/lib/introspect/decorated.js:54:24)\n    at JSONPopulator.visitClassDeclaration (/home/composer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-common/lib/serializer/jsonpopulator.js:83:60)\n    at JSONPopulator.visit (/home/composer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-common/lib/serializer/jsonpopulator.js:56:25)\n    at AssetDeclaration.accept (/home/composer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-common/lib/introspect/decorated.js:54:24)\n    at Serializer.fromJSON (/home/composer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-common/lib/serializer.js:180:26)\n    at ensureConnected.then (/home/composer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-connector-composer/lib/businessnetworkconnector.js:634:43)\n    at <anonymous>\n    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)"
  }
}
```

Did anyone managed to create nested asset and it works for him? I would be really thankful for any help, suggestion, anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To include an Item within an Item which is what your model defines, you would use JSON similar to this:

```
{
 "$class": "org.dps.track.Item",
 "itemId": "2",
 "name": "2",
 "serialNumber": "2",
 "comment": "2",
 "items": [{"$class": "org.dps.track.Item",
 "itemId": "3",
 "name": "3",
 "serialNumber": "3",
 "comment": "3"}]
```

}

However, I wonder if what you actually wanted was an array of **Relationships** to other existing items in which case you would have this model and JSON:

```
asset Item identified by itemId{
o String itemId
o String name
o String serialNumber
o String comment
--> Item [] items optional
} 

{
 "$class": "org.dps.track.Item",
 "itemId": "A",
 "name": "A",
 "serialNumber": "A",
 "comment": "A",
 "items2": ["org.dps.track.Item#C","org.dps.track.Item#B"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You're the best!